# Create stored procedure to move data from stage_table to fact_table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Create stored procedure to move data from stage_table to fact_table. Scheme_name will be populated based on product_code and agency_code. Stage_table has to look up dim_table based on product_code and agency_code. when look up doesn't match, scheme_name to be written as N/A.

Query to be written in SQL Server. I tried writing the query below, but getting subquery returned more than 1 value error. Any help would be appreciated.

Stage_table

```
Policy holder.  Phone number    
------------------------------
John.            456
Jack.            789
Jaxon.           101
Joshna.          121
Jenifer.         214
Joy.             453
Jordan.          343


Product_code.     Agency_code
-----------------------------
AAA.              PP
SSS.              SS11
SSS.              AA11
VVV.              AA11
VVV.              RR
QQQ.              QQ11
VVV.              VV11
```

Dim_lookup

```
Product_code  Agency_code.  Scheme_name
---------------------------------------
AAA.           AA11.        A
QQQ.           QQ11.        Q
VVV.           VV11.        V
SSS.           SS11.        S
```

---query for stage_table to lookup dim_lookup

```
UPDATE stage_table set stage_table.scheme_name = ( 
case 
when stage_table.product_code = dim_lookup.product_code and stage_table.agency_code=dim_lookup.agency_code 
then dim_lookup.scheme_name

Else 'NA'

END from dim_lookup)
```

---query to create stored procedure to move data to fact_table

```
Create procedure Move_table
As
Begin
    Insert into fact_table
    Select*from stage_table
End

Exec Move_table
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. In order to improve your chances to get an accurate answer to your question, please read the first couple of paragraphs in the [tsql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tsql/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the part where you assign the scheme.

Try doing an update with join instead:

```
UPDATE a
set a.scheme_name = case when a.product_code = b.product_code and b.agency_code=b.agency_code then b.scheme_name Else 'NA' end

from stage_table as a left join dim_lookup as b
on a.product_code = b.product_code and b.agency_code=b.agency_code
```

Comment: Hi Ben, I think I need to use left outer join in place of inner join as i need to fetch the rows which don't match.

Comment: Yes, of course - my answer would never have hit the "NA" result.
Change inner join to left, and it should work I think. I edited my answer to show this

Comment: Thanks Ben, I also need to create a stored procedure to move data from stage_table to fact_table as per this  question -------create stored procedure to move data from stage_table to fact_table. Scheme_name will be populated based on product_code and agency_code. Stage_table has to look up dim_table based on product_code and agency_code. when look up doesn't match, scheme_name to be written as N/A.  Could you please let me know if my second SQL query is right?